# Ubuntu/Windows dual boot

Tags: grub, ubuntu-10.10

After Installing Windows 7, I lost Grub and was unable to boot Ubuntu. After booting Puppy Linux using live CD by mistake I also deleted the boot/grub folder on the Ubuntu partition. How can I boot into Ubuntu(10.10, Grub2) now?

Comment: You may want to pop this over to askubuntu.com...

Comment: @Rory, the question is perfectly on-topic here on Super User.

Comment: @DMA57361 - okay. It was just that askubuntu has a whole section on exactly this issue: http://askubuntu.com/q/18566/7163

Comment: @Rory in which case migration is even less desirable, as it will create a duplicate on the target site (although frankly the quality of the linked post is a bit low in my opinion - link-only answers with no real info, etc). But I'm sure there's likely to be multiple duplicates on both sites (and probably [Unix/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) as well).

Comment: @DMA57361 - no worries, I have popped up an answer. :-)

Comment: @Rory, looks good - all the potential dupes I was finding on SU used `boot/grub`, which the user has lost in this case, so it probably warrants its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two how-to's I found from https://askubuntu.com/q/18566/7163:

- [How to restore the Ubuntu grub bootloader](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708)
- [Reinstalling from LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD)

That first one seems most useful. Key steps:

1. boot from a CD
2. use sudo fdisk -l to find the device name of your Ubuntu drive, something like “/dev/sda5″
3. sudo mkdir /media/sda5
4. sudo mount /dev/sda5 /media/sda5
5. sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/sda5 /dev/sda